# drop down menu starts in expanded state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a drop down table in jquery, but it is in expanded state when I run it in the browser. I want the table to be in collapsed state when i open it for the first time. Can u help me fix what's wrong?? Please suggest some changes to the code.

---

```
    (function($){
        $.fn.jExpand = function(){
            var element = this;

            $(element).find("tr:odd").addClass("odd");
            $(element).find("tr:not(.odd)").hide();
            $(element).find("tr:table").show();

            $(element).find("tr.odd").click(function() {
                $(this).next("tr").toggle();
            });

        }    
    })(jQuery); 

     $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#report tr:odd").addClass("odd");
                $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
                $("#report tr:table").show();

                $("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
                    $(this).next("tr").toggle();
                    $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
                });
                //$("#report").jExpand();
            });

<table id="report">
        <tr>
            <th>Notices</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>January</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><div class="arrow"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <table>
                <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
                </table>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post the markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The markup you posted isn't properly nested, although it might be that's how you posted them. Anyhow a double-check won't hurt. Since the inner table is inside a `td` after the inner table is closed we need a `</td></tr>` before the outre table is closed.

Secondly you're using `$("#report tr:table").show();` which throws `unsupported pseudo: table` you can instead use:

```
$("#report tr").find("table").closest("tr").show();
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/49xdjeo4/1/)

**======**

**EDIT:**

Modified the code so it only shows the outer .odd rows and expand when clicked:

```
$("#report > tbody > tr:odd").addClass("odd");
$("#report > tbody > tr:not(.odd)").hide();
//$("#report tr").find("table").closest("tr").show();

$("#report").on('click', 'tr.odd', function () {
    $(this).next("tr").toggle();
    $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
});
```

[**updated jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/49xdjeo4/2/)

Comment: Check the edit and let me know if changes to be made.